# How to make a linebreak in Display Only item in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

I'm working on an app in Oracle Apex. I have a **Display Only item** built by using a Dynamic Action and Setting the value through the following PL/SQL Function Body

```
DECLARE
v_message varchar2(1000);
v_notification varchar2(10000);

BEGIN
FOR item IN
(SELECT * FROM NOTIFICATIONS)
LOOP
    v_message := item.notification_msg || chr(10) || chr(10);
    v_notification := v_notification || v_messsage;
END LOOP;
return v_notification;

END;
```

The problem is that the Line break characters are being ignored in the rendered page. Can you tell me how to display the item with the Line break characters rendered.

Let the Notifications table be like this

```
ID     NOTIFICATION_MSG
1      Last date for the application is 18th Dec.
2      Office closed from 25th dec to 1st Jan.
```

I want the rendered Display Only Item in the page to be

```
Last date for the application is 18th Dec.

Office closed from 25th dec to 1st Jan.
```

But it is rendered as

```
Last date for the application is 18th Dec.Office closed from 25th dec to 1st Jan.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question and let us know the actual and expected output with details(sample data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `chr(10) || chr(10)`: did you mean `chr(13) || chr(10)` instead?

---

Anyway: include `<br>` as a line break, e.g.

```
v_message := item.notification_msg || '<br>'
```

Don't forget to set **Escape special characters** to "No" for that display item.

Comment: I've tried what you've said, I've set the Escape special characters to No and also used the <br> as line break. But the <br> characters are just rendered as normal text, not creating a line break i.e for the example mentioned in the question it is rendered as `Last date for the application is 18th Dec<br>.Office closed from 25th dec to 1st Jan.<br>`

Comment: I tried it on my Apex 18.2 and it *works* ... Tested it before posting the answer.

Comment: Don't know why but it's working now. Thanks